# How to convert form MSAccess to MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ms-access

I have to maintain a project that was coded by others. In that project they used MSAccess database (.mdb). I have little knowledge about C# and database connection using C#. Now I need to convert to MySQL from MSAccess.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it a one time activity of migrating the database or complete rework of application in MySQL

Comment: Its just one time migration. I just need to convert the application so that it can use mysql database instead of MSAccess.

Comment: OK for migration you can one of many available tools these links can be of your help : `http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php` and `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html` Regarding codeing C# with MySQL you require MySql connector (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and more help at `http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp`

Comment: Do I need to update all the connection and query too? Or there is a quick way to do this?

Comment: I do not know if some tool is available for the same. You need to change every connection (as it has changed), thoroughly test the application and change only queries which are required as per the app behavior. Summarizing it as an answer, please mark the same if it solves your problem.

Comment: (This question would have been rather off-topic in 2014, since it is not really answerable - it is very broad. If it is a request for a conversion tool then that is off-topic too, since it's a recommendation request).

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be broken in two parts:

- Migrate data
- Update app to use new database

1.Migrate data : Many tools are available to do the same 2 of the urls being :

- http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php
- [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-‌​access-export.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Baccess-export.html)
- You can also write a custom application if you want to customize the data migration.

2.Update application :

- First you need to change all the connection objects to utilize new database,
- you may also have to change the queries, but prior to doing all of them, test the application
- change only the queries which are required.
- MySQL with C# help : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to perform below steps.

**Step 1:** Migrate your existing MS ACCESS database to My SQL, you can use MS Access to My SQL tool such as ‘*Bullzip*’  , you can create temp DB i.e. **TempAccessDB**

**Step 2:**  Write Script where you need to write insert statements which will migrate your **TempAccessDB** database to your application’s My SQL database.

Below is an example script for MS SQL(not MySQL)

```
 /********* Transfer Student Table Data ***********
 SET @sqlStatement=N'INSERT INTO  '+ @newDBName_Full +'Student]
                                 (StudentID,StudentName)
                        SELECT  StudentID,SName
                        FROM  '+@oldDBName_Full +'tblStudent] a
                        WHERE NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM '+ @newDBName_Full +'Student] b WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(b.StudentName))= LTRIM(RTRIM(a.sName)))'
exec sp_executesql @sqlStatement

 /********* Transfer Grade Data***********
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it is just a 'one-time' thing, you can do the following...

1. In you MSAccess table, right-click then Export > ODBC Database

[image: Step 1]

2. Enter the table name you want or just use the provided name by default

[image: Step 2]

3. [You will be prompted to select an ODBC Data Source] Select the source (actually the target connection). If you do not have this yet, you can search on how to create an ODBC connection... pretty easy. :). Then click OK.

[image: Step 3]

This will then immediately create the table in your MySql and insert all the records.
Just a note though that it uses utf-8 encoding. For my case, I had Japanese characters in my data and they were converted to something else. Don't know though how to solve this part yet. Apart from that, you should be okay.

No 3rd-party app or coding needed. :D